# Tableau Filter Using a column

Tags: tableau-api

I am working on tableau project and have encountered a problem.

I have a NAME Dimensions and Year Dimensions I want to get all the list of names based using year filter, and this name list will be used for filtering the data.

I tried creating the set of Name dimensions with condition in by formula

```
SUM[Year] = [Year_Selector]
```

Year_Selector is the parameter with range 2002 to 2019 year.

How should I get the list of all names for a particular year. I do not want to use year in filter block.

Answer (score 2):

Don't aggregate the year.

```
[Year] = [Year_Selector]
```